# Delete the same row from two different NSMutableArray in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray called "items" and its data populated in uitableviewcontroller. I am using uiseachcontroller to search data from "items" array and add the search results to "filteredTableData" which is a NSMutableArray also displayed using the same table view.

When i delete a row from "items" it works fine. However when i delete from "filteredTableData" from search results, how can i remove the same object from "items" array?

below is my code:

```
     if(isFiltered)
     [filteredTableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     else
     [items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
       [self savePasswordlistItems];
```

Any help?

Comment: Is the object you wish to remove unique? If so, simply call `removeObject:`.

Comment: @rmaddy, "items" array is a subclass of nsobject and it contains few NSStrings properties. I am encoding them using a "Key".

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. Is each object in your `items` array unique or can two or more of your custom classes represent the same data?

Comment: Yes. It's unique. How do I get a reference to the object I am deleting from "filteredTableData" and then remove the same object in "items" array?

Answer (score 0):

Are you reloading the table view after you delete the item? Sometimes it needs to redraw it again with [tableView reloadData];

Comment: Yes. I am reloading it. However the data doesn't get deleted after reloading. The problem is that I am deleting the row from "filteredTableData" array which contains the result from search. When it gets deleted, the source array supposed to be deleted as well? If not so, i need to get a reference of the deleting object and then delete the same object object from "items" array. This is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Thanks @rmaddy and @Rodrigo. I managed to delete the object by getting a reference of object and then delete using removeObjectIdenticalTo

Here is the code if someone need

```
PasswordItem *item;

           if(isFiltered)
             {
                item = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [filteredTableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [items removeObjectIdenticalTo: item];

             } else 
             {
                item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             }

              NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
              [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

              [self savePasswordlistItems];
              [self.tableView setEditing:NO];
              [tableView reloadData];
```